# PHP set permissions and delete folder - files

Tags: php, nginx, permissions, chmod

I'm using PHP 7.3 + nginx on a Centos. My application contains a folder, that is mounted, containing files from another server. I need to delete those files once I don't have any use for them. I used the code below to delete those files. The code works fine, but some of these files  are created wtih more restrictions(only read) and my application can only delete them if I manually set a chmod -R 775 on them.

```
function remove_dir($dir) {
  if (is_dir($dir)) {
    $objects = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
      if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
        if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir"){
           remove_dir($dir."/".$object); 
        }else {
      unlink   ($dir."/".$object);
    }
      }
    }
    reset($objects);
    rmdir($dir);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I've tried this:

```
$command = "chmod -R 775 ".$folder;
exec($command);
```

but always endup with:

> WARNING: [pool www] child n said into stderr: "chmod: changing permissions of '/folder/file': Operation not permitted"

Is it possible to set those permissions, or I need to create those file I want to delete with the right permissions already set?

I tried this one, but It gives me permission error too.

```
$command = "rm -rf {$local}";
exec($command, $output, $status);
```

> said into stderr: "rm: cannot remove 'folder/file': Permission denied"

---

---

***EDIT: So I read many recomendations and I figure out is better not to do this via a webapp even if it just run internally on my company. I created a script and i'm just gonna run via a crontab. Solve my problem, without any security concerns.***

Comment: It depends on the uid that is running the PHP proces relative to the file permissions of the files/folders youre trying to delete. I suppose when you chmod the files manually, you are using a more privileged uid than the one your PHP process is using.

Comment: yes, on my server console I'm running as root

Comment: Check the uid of the PHP process that's giving you the permission denied errors. I'm sure it doesn't run as root (and thus raises permission denied errors). You can try elevating the privileges of the PHP process, but I wouldn't recommend that. I think you have to find another workaround, or keep chmod'ing the files manually.

Comment: I run shell_exec('whoami'), it returned: nginx. do you know how can I add more permissions?

Comment: Try shell_exec('id -u');

Comment: i got this result -> 994

Comment: You can compare that uid against those of the files on the mounted volume. E.g. ls -la /that/volume, then id -u some-owner. If those uid's are lower, you will not have permission to write/delete those files by default. You need to set those file permissions to writable for non-owners (using a privileged user like root).

If the files on the mounted volumes always belong to some user in the same group, you can try playing around with that. Like adding the PHP process uid to that group.

Answer (score 0):

Example for changing permissions :

```
<?php 
$fn = './test.txt';
chmod($fn, 0777);
```

Notice that we put 0 before 777 to ask PHP to interpret it as an octal number.

Comment: I've tried this one, but I give permission issues too